# Highcharts | Custom plotOptions->series->dataLabels

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

I'm trying to do a really specific graph with HighChart, I hope I will be clear.
I give an example, I have votes for each country like this :

- France 2 yes / 1 No
- England 1 yes / 0 No

I have to display in plotOptions->series->dataLabels the information like this :

- France yes : 2 votes/66% Because we have 3 votes in total for France
- France no : 1 votes/33%
- England yes : 1 votes/100% Because we have 1 vote in total for England
- England no : 0 votes/0%

In Php / Symfony 3 / Javascript I did something like this :

```
$ob->plotOptions->series(
            array(
                'dataLabels' => array(
                    'enabled' => true,
                    'formatter' => new Expr('function () {
                            return this.y + "<br/>(" + Math.round(((this.y / '.$numberOfResultsByCountry.') * 100) * 100) / 100 + " %)"
                        }')
                )
            )
        );
```

It works, but the calcul is wrong, $numberOfResultsByCountry change in function of my country, for France the value is 3, for England the value is 1.

How can I custom the dataLabels for each result ? I checked doc (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels) and It seems that plotOptions->series->dataLabels does not accept an array here. So I have no idea how to do it.

I hope I have been clear to explain my problem.

TY

Comment: I think that you may add your total votes number as a 'value' parameter, and then find this parameter using this.point.value. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/m28ob7r7/

Comment: Wow thanks I didn't know I could custom this.point values like total. Thanks this is exactly what I needed. Can you create a proper answer so I can accept your answer ?

Comment: Happy to read that my idea worked for you. I have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can add your total votes number as a 'total' parameter, and then find this parameter using this.point.total.

```
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
      type: 'category'
    },
    series: [{
      type: 'column',
      keys: ['x', 'y', 'total'],
      data: [
        [0, 3, 5],
        [1, 1, 4],
        [2, 3, 3],
        [3, 0, 4]
      ],
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
          return this.y + "<br/>(" + Math.round(((this.y / this.point.total) * 100) * 100) / 100 + " %)"
        }
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

I am using keys for adding new parameter to my points. You can find information about this parameter here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.keys

Here you can find an example how it can work: 
http://jsfiddle.net/m28ob7r7/

Regards,

Comment: Thanks Grzegorz ;)